# Need help to set up 2x4 + 1x8 Gb Ram

Tags: memory, setup

I'm using 2x4 Gb sticks (1866 Mhz) (4 DDMI slots on motherboard, max 32 Gb).
I accidentally bought a 8 Gb stick of the same type (instead of 2x4 Gb) .
How should I set up this version of 16 Gb Rams for best performance?
(I will buy another 8 gb stick to match it in the future).

Thank you in regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make use of dual channels, place the 2x4 Gb sticks in the same colored slots closet to the CPU. If they are all the same color, consult your motherboard's manual. Place the 1x8 Gb stick in the closest off color slot. Once you get anther 8 Gb stick, swap the 2x4 Gb sticks with the 8's so the 8's are closer to the CPU.

Comment: @zsedan If you have any more questions, let me know. Also, this answer assumes a dual channel motherboard. Check your manual to double check if you are not sure.

Comment: I know everything regarding my motherboard (Gigabyte 970A-UD3P) and the usual dual channel placements. I'm just asking because someone said I can also match the 4 Gb and 8 Gb in 1 channel (slot 1 and 3), and leave the other 4 Gb in the other channel alone (slot 4), beacuse it will see the first channel as 2x8 Gb via Flex Technology, which I never heard of.

Comment: @zsedan I haven't heard of that before either. It would still work in that configuration, it just wouldn't have all the benefits of dual channel. [Here](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/intel-stakes-vision-pc-future-775-launch,830-28.html) is a small article (from 2004) about it.

Comment: @zsedan It looks like the Flex Technology is a step between single and dual channel. If you had two *different* size RAM sticks, it would give you a boost in performance, but not as good as dual channel. So in other words: If you have two sticks the same size, keep them together.

Comment: Yepp I understand, question is does an AMD motherboard have this technology, since it's an intel thing.
I'll just do the usual method 2x4 and 8 alone, and will add a same 8 gb stick a few months later.

Comment: @zsedan It does not look like AMD uses Flex.

Comment: I solved my problem, put it up for sale, and ordered the correct 2x4 kit, best option : )
I would like to thank you again for your help!